# How to identify and kill the child processes which were created during an API call whose parent processes have been killed ? (python code required)

Tags: python, linux, api, server, process

I have created an API in python using tornado. For a given URL, it returns me with a summary of data on that URL. There are several processes which are still there (and not running, but consuming space). For example, in the image provided, I can see 'chrome_crashpad' which is not running but still consuming space. So, I am looking for a python code where we make sure that for API hit, the processes which were created are deleted at the end , so that it doesn't affect the server (over longer period of time). In other words, the junk processes whose parents have been killed should also be identified and deleted.

I tried and was unable to identify if these processes are junk processes or not. Also , was unable to identify if the process which is there and TIME shown is 00:00:00 is parent process or not. Need more clarity on this. But, the motive of this is to delete all the junk and zombie processes so that for a longer duration of time, the server remains stable.[processes shown at my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09tSf.png)

Comment: I don't know, is any library for python (i think it is), but.... you can call system command `ps axjfww`. Filter this by column PPID. All processess with PPID '1' has killed parent, and moved to parent 'INIT' for SystemV mode, or 'SYSTEMD' for new systemd. Clue, is parent number 1. If you found that, check if column UID, for simply pre filtering all processes outside your serive. Finally test 'COMMAND' column, to be sure, this is the process you try to find. Finally, read column 'PID', this is probably the process you want to kill. Be sure, this is not your main process, do additional test. Ma

Comment: You can use lib `psutil` to implement the check